# Using ColdFusion debugging behind AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-elb

I am using AWS ELB on two ColdFusion servers. I am able to get the client's local ip using `#cgi.http_x_forwarded_for#` but I can't turn on debugging b/c the only IP it recognizes is the IP of the ELB. Enabling debugging in this manner exposes the robust exception info to the public, which is obviously not a good idea.

Is it possible to get CF admin to recognize the client IP address through some manner of IIS header re-writing or something similar? Or modify the ColdFusion debugger to use the http_x_forwarded_for?

Comment: Or perhaps you could setup your ELB to pass the client's ip through. [Elastic Load Balancing adds support for Proxy Protocol](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/07/30/elastic-load-balancing-now-supports-proxy-protocol/) (EDIT) after reading up on that a bit it might not help. Looks like it might pass the ip in another header. Not sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. I added the following to c:\coldfusion10\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
    protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" 
    remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" 
    protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />
```

Comment: Where in server.xml did you add this? I tried adding it within this tag with the other valve definitions but it didn't work:

<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just before the </host> closing tag. make sure you restart both iis and the cf service.

Comment: I am also using CF10. I have yet to test it on cf11 or other versions.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working in the CGI scope in CF11, but it is available here #GetHttpRequestData().headers['X-Forwarded-For']#